# Why can I create Users with the same UID?

Tags: user-management

My understanding of UIDs is that is a unique positive integer assigned by a Unix-like operating system to each user. Each user is identified to the system by its UID, and user names are generally used only as an interface for humans.

How can two users have the same UID, isn't this a conflict for my system and packages?

```
root@kdc:~# id test12
uid=1005(test10) gid=1000(server) groups=1005(test10)
root@kdc:~# id test13
uid=1005(test10) gid=1000(server) groups=1005(test10)
root@kdc:~#
```

I've added two users with same UID and GID: `test12` and  `test13`

The output of `/etc/passwd`:

```
client@kdc:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep test12
test12:x:1005:1000::/home/test12:/bin/sh
client@kdc:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep test13
test13:x:1005:1000::/home/test13:/bin/sh
```

I added the users by `useradd -ou 1005 -g1000 username.`

I got confused what is the purpose of this, and can it affect permissions and user logs etc. So now if a user is added with `uid=0` and `gid=0` will has privileges like a root account?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer here is that Linux does not protect you from yourself.

If you really want to `su root` and go into the /etc files and give all the users the same UID, you can. It's just a text file.

But you really shouldn't and it will have unintended consequences.

Comment: my question is why the system accept this ?

Comment: What do you mean "accept" it? How would it NOT accept it? this is like being a chef and asking why the soup allowed you to put too much salt in it.


In terms of modern computing, you're probably used to an RDBMS mentality, where contraints on important things like IDs keep you from shooting yourself in the foot. Linux user IDs are much more primitive and have no internal checking or correction.

Comment: i added the user with useradd -ou command and didn't change /etc/passwd file

Comment: Right, and by using `useradd -o` you recognize that you're outside of the norm `adduser`. As @psusi mentioned, it creates two logins pointing to the same ID as far as file permissions etc. It probably also creates issues since that is not a normal use case and is no doubt untested with lots of packages.

Comment: i asked this to know the reason , inst this community for discussing questions , i would like to know

Comment: Answer: to have 2 logins point to identical filesystem permissions.

Comment: ok the both will have same priviliges

Comment: The reason is: the system doesn't *stop* you from doing this. It's not a "feature" built in with a purpose.

Comment: If you want to shoot yourself in the foot, linux is perfectly willing to let you load the gun and pull the trigger. It's only an operating system, if you think you have a good reason to do something weird it's not going to second guess you.

Comment: @Josh of course it is, there are valid reasons to have multiple users with the same UID, see my answer for one example.

Answer (score 56):

There are actually valid reasons for this. For instance, I used to work in a lab where we each had our own computer but our `$HOME` was in a shared drive exported by a server. So, my `$HOME` was

```
/users/terdon
```

Since the `/users` folder was actually not on my local machine but exported over NFS, for any analysis that was heavy on I/O, I would use data stored on my local hard drives so as not to burden the lab's network. To that end I, and everybody else, had two users: one that was system-wide and one that was local to the machine in question. The local user's home was

```
/home/localuser
```

However, I needed to have full access to my files whether I was logged in as `terdon` or as `localuser` and the way our sysadmin had implemented that was by giving both `localuser` and `terdon` the same UID. That way, I could freely manipulate my local files irrespective of which user I was currently logged in as.

Comment: In support of this answer, it's worth noting that some setups such as virtual email hosting use this to great effect, i.e. a great number of virtual email accounts sharing a single UID - the documentation for the Dovecot mail server actually suggests this as an optional approach at http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserIds#mailusers

Comment: wouldn't `chmod 666` have the same affects?

Comment: @GIJoe that would allow both users to read/write but it wouldn't preserve ownership which could be a problem. Also, not all files can be set to those permissions (ssh keys for example) and it is not practical to need to play with permissions all the time.

Answer (score 16):

It's actually fairly common to have two users with the same ID. On FreeBSD, there are usually two users with UID 0: root and toor. Root uses the built-in /bin/sh shell, and toor  uses a different shell, usually bash.

Answer (score 14):

Unix systems & Linux generally do nothing to prohibit duplicates in the `/etc/passwd` file. The intent of this file is to associate a UID with a physical name that can be display by command line tools such as `ls` when user's are listing out files.

```
$ ls -n | head -5
total 986000
drwxrwxr-x.   3 1000 1000      4096 Feb 13 19:51 1_archive_sansa
-rw-rw-r--.   1 1000 1000    760868 Dec 16 08:21 2.18.x Database Scheme.jpg
-rw-rw-r--.   1 1000 1000       972 Oct  6 20:26 abcdefg
drwxrwxr-x.   2 1000 1000      4096 Feb 11 03:34 advanced_linux_programming
```

The other intended purpose of this file is to specify what shell a user will get when they login.

```
$ getent passwd saml
saml:x:1000:1000:saml:/home/saml:/bin/bash
```

A common attack vector on Unix type systems is to add lines such as these to a system's `/etc/passwd` file:

```
$ getent passwd r00t
r00t:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

$ getent passwd toor
toor:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

The role of the `/etc/passwd` file is *NOT* meant to solely track user accounts. The role of tracking username's and passwords is the responsibility of the `/etc/shadow` file. Files such as `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are really meant to provide a human readable name when your system is listing files from disks.

Remember that your files are written to the disk using UID/GID's not actual names.

```
$ stat afile 
  File: ‘afile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 6560621     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    saml)   Gid: ( 1000/    saml)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2014-02-27 15:54:21.852697029 -0500
Modify: 2014-02-27 15:54:21.852697029 -0500
Change: 2014-02-27 15:54:21.852697029 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Notice the `Uid:` and `Gid:`, the numbers are what's actually written to the disk!

Answer (score 12):

Two users can have the same UID because it is just a number in a text file so you can set it to anything you want, including a value that is already used.  As you have seen though, doing so is not a good idea.

Comment: how the system deal with users then ? sharing permissions

Comment: @nux, they are both the same user.  They can just have a different username/password for the purpose of logging in.

Comment: @bigbadonk420, the term "supported" is rather nebulous.  It certainly is something you have always been able to do on unix systems and it used to be a fairly common backdoor to set up another user that has uid 0 so you can log in and effectively be root, without needing to know or change the password on the normal root user.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 it is supported, there are cases where this is useful, see my answer for one example.

Answer (score 10):

In Linux, all users and groups are actually just numbers. That's what the output of the `id` command you posted shows.

The `/etc/passwd` file maps user *names* to user *IDs* (numbers) and in the example you have provide, you've simply mapped two usernames to the same user ID.

Effectively, you've created one user, `test12`, ID 1005, who also has a second username `test13`. However the system will map UID 1005 to the first username it finds, which would be `test12`

Linux "lets" you do this because there's no system to prevent you from doing this. `/etc/passwd` is just a text file, usernames are mapped to the UID found for their entry in that file, UIDs are mapped to the first username found in that file.

But what you've created is a confusing situation for other systams administrators; avoid it by changing the UID of `test13`

Comment: this is my test virtual machine man , my question is there a purpose to map two users for the same uid

Comment: The only purpose I can think of is to give a UID a second, aliased, username. But this is undefined behavior and not recommended. Really this is an undesirable situation: you're better off with a 1:1 relationship between usernames and UIDs

Comment: thats why i asked this question i needed to know , i felt that it is a confusing way

Comment: It is confusing; that's why you shouldn't do it. It doesn't have a "purpose", it's more a misuse of the `/etc/passwd` file. But there's no means in place to *prevent* you from doing this. Does that make sense?

Comment: a user mentioned that the goal is to have 2 logins point to identical filesystem permissions.

Comment: Yes and that would work *to a point*, you can `chown test13 someFile` and it will be owned by both `test12` and `tes13` **because they both are the same user, UID 1005**. A much better way to give two logins access to the same file would be using a group, or ACLs.

Answer (score 7):

**The reason that this is allowed today, is simply because the system doesn't prevent it.**

If this changed, then it would break those systems where admins have had a use for this feature, (see Terdon's example). So it has never been changed, and I don't think it ever will.

Originally there was only the passwd and group files, and they served their purpose. there was no *adduser* command, no *addgroup*, the files were edited by root using vi or ed.

There were a few quirks !

In order to remember the next user-id to use, it was common for admins to have a special user as the last line which had a user-name of `!` (because `!` was an invalid user name) and that entry was used to store the next user-id. Crude, I admit, but It worked! So why bust a gut making it more complicated, akin to agile development today.

There were known flaws. The main being, that it had to be world readable, so that  utilities like `ls` could could map `user-id => name`. This meant anybody could see everybody's encrypted password, and all the users and id's in the system.

Some Unix systems began introducing a couple of shell scripts `adduser` `addgroup`, often these were ignored, because they were a inconsistent between Unixes, so most people just carried on with the manual edit.

It took quite a few years, before the `shadow` password file was invented, this provided a little more security, by hiding the encrypted passwords. Again, just enough complexity was added, but it was still fairly crude and simple. The utilities `useradd` and `groupadd` were introduced, which kept `shadow` and `shadow-` updated. To start with, these were often simple shell script wrappers around vendors proprietary *adduser/addgroup* utilities. Again it was just enough to keep going.

Networks of computers were growing up, people were working on several at a time to get jobs done, so admin of the `passwd/group` files was becoming a nightmare, especially with NFS, so in comes Yellow Pages also known as NIS to alleviate the burden.

It was becoming obvious by now that something a bit more flexible was needed, and PAM was was invented. So if you were really sophisticated and wanted a centralised, secure, unique-id'ed, all bells and whistles authentication system you would call out to a central server to authenticate, maybe a Radius server, LDAP server or Active directory.

The world had grown up. But the passwd/group/shadow files still remained for us smaller users/developers/labs. We still didn't really require the all bells and whistles. I guess the philosophy had changed a bit by now to, *"If you were going to make it better, you wouldn't use it at all"*, so don't worry about it.

This is why I don't think the simple passwd file will ever change. There's no point any more, and it's just great for those £30 Raspberry Pi's with 2 maybe 3 user's monitoring temperature, and twitter feeds. OK, You just have to be a bit careful with your user-id's if you want them unique, and there's nothing to prevent the enthusiast from wrapping *useradd* in a script which first selects the next unique id from a database (file) to set a unique id, if that's what you want. It is open source after all.

Answer (score 4):

The `/etc/passwd` file just maps symbolic usernames to the real userID.  If you deliberately make two symbolic names that map to one userID then it will let you.

That doesn't mean it is a good idea to actually do it.  Some people may have found very specific usage cases where they can take advantage of this feature, but in general you should not do it.

Linux (and other UNIXes) take the opinion that the administrator knows what they are doing.  If you tell it to do something stupid then that's your own fault, in much the same way that if you tell your car to drive over a cliff you can't go to the manufacturers and ask why the car allowed you to do this.

Comment: why it was mentioned as a bug ?

Answer (score 2):

There are identifiers that the operating system expects to be unique, but they are used for tracking hardware.  The knowledge that a particular [Universally Unique IDentifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) corresponds to a hard drive containing system files may help it to continue operating if the hardware configuration changes.  Microsoft calls these Globally Unique IDentifiers and uses them to track all Windows software.  Ironically, these acronyms were poorly chosen.

From the perspective of the OS, most user and group identifier changes amount to changing its outside interface.  It could function normally despite collisions; mainly what is required of the system users and groups is that they exist.  It cannot know what the users require.  In situations like this, the Unix philosophy is that the OS should assume the administrators know what they are doing, and should help them do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I found some evidence that supports [andybalholm's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/427273/829702).

From *APUE*,  §8.15:

> Any process can find out its real and effective user ID and group ID. Sometimes,
>   however, we want to find out the login name of the user who’s running the program.
>   We could call `getpwuid`(`getuid`()), but what if a single user has multiple login
>   names, each with the same user ID? (**A person might have multiple entries in the
>   password file with the same user ID to have a different login shell for each entry**.) The system normally keeps track of the name we log in under (Section 6.8), and the `getlogin` function provides a way to fetch that login name.
>
> ....
>
> Given the login name, we can then use it to look up the user in the password file — to determine the login shell, for example—using `getpwnam`.

Btw, I would like to know if one can switch to another shell while logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you used `-o` (non-unique ID) which will allow you to create a duplicate UID.